# publickey authentication only works with existing ssh session

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, public-key

**`publickey` authentication only works for me if I've already got one ssh session open.**

I am trying to log into a host running Ubuntu 10.10 desktop with `publickey` authentication, and it fails when I first log in:

```
[me@my-laptop:~]$ ssh -vv host
...
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa
...
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: Next authentication method: password
me@hosts's password:
```

And the /var/log/auth.log output:

```
Jan 16 09:57:11 host sshd[1957]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for cpe-70-114-155-20.austin.res.rr.com [70.114.155.20] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jan 16 09:57:13 host sshd[1957]: pam_sm_authenticate: Called
Jan 16 09:57:13 host sshd[1957]: pam_sm_authenticate: username = [astacy]
Jan 16 09:57:13 host sshd[1959]: Passphrase file wrapped
Jan 16 09:57:15 host sshd[1959]: Error attempting to add filename encryption key to user session keyring; rc = [1]
Jan 16 09:57:15 host sshd[1957]: Accepted password for astacy from 70.114.155.20 port 42481 ssh2
Jan 16 09:57:15 host sshd[1957]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user astacy by (uid=0)
Jan 16 09:57:20 host sudo:   astacy : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/astacy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

The strange thing is that once I've got this first login session, I run the exact same ssh command, and `publickey` authentication works:

```
[me@my-laptop:~]$ ssh -vv host
...
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 277
...
[me@host:~]$
```

And the /var/log/auth.log output is:

```
Jan 16 09:59:11 host sshd[2061]: reverse mapping checking getaddrinfo for cpe-70-114-155-20.austin.res.rr.com [70.114.155.20] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT!
Jan 16 09:59:11 host sshd[2061]: Accepted publickey for astacy from 70.114.155.20 port 39982 ssh2
Jan 16 09:59:11 host sshd[2061]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user astacy by (uid=0)
```

What do I need to do to make `publickey` authentication work on the first login?

*NOTE*: When I installed Ubuntu 10.10, I checked the 'encrypt home folder' option.  I'm wondering if this has something to do with the log message "Error attempting to add filename encryption key to user session keyring"

Answer (score 1):

This [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ecryptfs-utils/+bug/295429) suggests that this might be encfs related. My guess is that first time it needs your password to read the authorized_keys2 on the encrypted volume. Without it, it does not have the decryption key.